# ¿Por qué al dar clic en un uno de los Dropdown se abren o desplegan todos en Svelte?

Tags: javascript, dropdown

Hola soy nuevo en el mundo de la programación y quisiera alguien me colaborara con un problema que tengo.

¿Por qué al momento de dar clic a un Dropdown en svelte, automáticamente se despliegan todos los Dropdown?

¿Como puedo limitar la escucha del evento del clic únicamente al Dropdown que le de clic?

Gradezco su ayuda de antemano

```
<script lang="ts">

  let isOpen = false;

  function handleUpdate(event) {
    isOpen = event.detail.isOpen;
  }
</script>

<Navbar color="light" light expand="md">
  <NavbarBrand href="/">sveltestrap</NavbarBrand>
  <NavbarToggler on:click={() => (isOpen = !isOpen)} />
  <Collapse {isOpen} navbar expand="md" on:update={handleUpdate}>
    <Nav class="ml-auto" navbar>
      <NavItem>
        <NavLink href="#components/">Components</NavLink>
      </NavItem>
      <NavItem>
        <NavLink href="https://github.com/bestguy/sveltestrap">GitHub</NavLink>
      </NavItem>
      <Dropdown nav inNavbar>
        <DropdownToggle nav caret>Options</DropdownToggle>
        <DropdownMenu right>
          <DropdownItem>Option 1</DropdownItem>
          <DropdownItem>Option 2</DropdownItem>
          <DropdownItem divider />
          <DropdownItem>Reset</DropdownItem>
        </DropdownMenu>
      </Dropdown>
    </Nav>
  </Collapse>
<NavbarToggler on:click={() => (isOpen = !isOpen)} />
  <Collapse {isOpen} navbar expand="md" on:update={handleUpdate}>
    <Nav class="ml-auto" navbar>
      <NavItem>
        <NavLink href="#components/">Components</NavLink>
      </NavItem>
      <NavItem>
        <NavLink href="https://github.com/bestguy/sveltestrap">GitHub</NavLink>
      </NavItem>
      <Dropdown nav inNavbar>
        <DropdownToggle nav caret>Options</DropdownToggle>
        <DropdownMenu right>
          <DropdownItem>Option 1</DropdownItem>
          <DropdownItem>Option 2</DropdownItem>
          <DropdownItem divider />
          <DropdownItem>Reset</DropdownItem>
        </DropdownMenu>
      </Dropdown>
    </Nav>
  </Collapse>
</Navbar>
```

Answer (score 0):

`isOpen` es el estado/variable en la que guardas el valor booleano sobre si un Dropdown (en realidad el componente `Collapse`) debería estar abierto o cerrado. El problema es que estás usando la misma variable para más de un Dropdown. Entonces cuando se cambia en uno de ellos se cambia para todos, y todos estarán abiertos o cerrados al mismo tiempo.

Posibles soluciones:

- Tener una variable por Dropdown en lugar de una única variable para todos los Dropdowns (`isOpen1`, `isOpen2`...): factible si tu componente es pequeño, pero se complica la cosa si tienes muchos Dropdowns.
- Modularizar el componente más, para que cada Dropdown sea independiente: parece que ya tienes un componente Dropdown, por lo que la idea sería mover la lógica que controla `isOpen` a dentro del componente en sí.